# UNION queries in Access 2007 SP2/Access 2010 fail with error 3360 "query is too complex". Worked fine in prior versions. Is there a fix?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I've been using a few simple union queries with no problems in Access 2003 and then in Access 2007. With Access 2007 SP2/Access 2010, these queries now fail with **error 3360 Query is too complex** even when no filters are used. (OS doesn't matter - same problem on XP SP3 through Win7 64-bit). The same .mdb on earlier systems works without a problem. What's going on here?

If I change "UNION ALL" to just "UNION", the query works, but that's not an acceptable solution since a memo field is part of the query output and will be truncated.

What changed to break union queries? What is the fix?

I'd prefer to use temp tables only as a last resort.

Comment: Please post your query, there may be a simple solution (http://dbaspot.com/forums/ms-access/345950-what-limitation-query-when-error-3360-query-toocomplex-appear.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should try to engineer out the need for a UNION? I always see UNIONs as a form of denormalization, and avoid them except where they're absolutely necessary. A structure that requires them is one that I'd consider redesigning.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up on Allen Brown's site about 6 months ago.  On his [Converting to Access 2007](http://allenbrowne.com/access2007.html) he had a forum link to
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3803279-2.php

One workaround to try is to do a select * at the beginning of the Union Query at the
front, i.e. with the selected fields:

```
SELECT qryUnion.*, qryUnion.FirstField, etc...
```

Comment: Vamping on this, I was having the problem and added ',*' to the end of the select clause. It worked, but I noticed that for some reason it only added one field, used as a WHERE criteria in the underlying queries. I then removed the * and added in that one field. Hey presto, all working. So my conclusion was that underlying WHERE fields need to be included. Pity that JET gets less reliable with every release.

Comment: @Ben Agree that it is a shame.  I'll keep that in mind.  This still works for me most of the time.  I haven't gotten the query too complex error that often, the rare occasion that I do get it usually forces me to use temp tables.